pip not using keyring credentials
I'm trying to use pip to install a package from a GitLab registry. I have stored my credentials via keyring following the official documentation, despite this I am still prompted for username/password:
$ which pip
/home/timo/python_venvs/my_venv/bin/pip
$ which keyring
/home/timo/python_venvs/my_venv/bin/keyring
$ echo <MY_TOKEN> | keyring set https://gitlab.com/api/v4/groups/<MY_GROUP_ID>/-/packages/pypi/simple <MY_TOKEN_NAME>
$ pip install --keyring-provider import -i https://gitlab.com/api/v4/groups/<MY_GROUP_ID>/-/packages/pypi/simple <MY_PACKAGE>
User for gitlab.com:
...

What is the issue here? Why is pip not reading the credentials from keygen?
